# Make UIView and contents expand to fill available horizontal space in UIToolbar with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` and a `UIView` containing two `UITextField` controls, all within a `UIToolbar`.

This is a screenshot of my storyboard: http://i.8px.co/x8eC.png.

I'd like to create something similar to this: http://i.8px.co/1hvY.png.

I'm trying to make the `UIView` and its children expand to fill the available horizontal space in the `UIToolbar` with **Auto Layout**. I don't know how to accomplish what I want.

I experimented with a dirty solution for the UIView and was able to have it size somewhat correctly.

```
view.width = toolBar.frame.width - button.width 
// where view is the UIView, toolBar is the UIToolBar, and button is the UIBarButtonItem
```

I don't believe this is very elegant. This is done programmatically, the `UIView` doesn't conform to the standard `UIToolbar` margins, and the solution doesn't apply to the `UITextFields`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you'd have to do this programmatically.

Try this :

```
  self.toolBarview.frame = (CGRect) {.origin = self.toolBarview.frame.origin.x, self.toolBarview.frame.origin.y, .size = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - self.barButton.width - 40, self.toolBarview.frame.size.height};
```

Here toolBarview is the **UIView** which has the 2 **UITextField**'s. 40 is the **buffer** value that you need to subtract to give the padding.

**/* EDIT */**

You should give the appropriate **constraints** to the `UITextField` as shown below:

[image: Textfield Constraints]

Comment: This doesn't fully solve my problem. I already was able to change the width of the `UIView`, I also need to fit the `UITextField` children to the `UIView` width as described above.

Comment: Almost. I've played around with this concept but the UITextField and UIView continue off the screen for some reason.

Comment: Well, that's weird. Please take a look at this : https://www.dropbox.com/s/0kljk606ahvyhvd/TextIndent.zip?dl=0

Comment: What wasn't immediately obvious to me was that the buffer value varies between screen orientation/size. I had to play around with the value to get everything constrained properly on my iPhone. Maybe I'm misunderstanding (it's late) but is this the correct behavior?

Answer (score 1):

"I'm trying to make the UIView and its children expand to fill the available horizontal space in the UIToolbar with Auto Layout" You can't. The UIView is in a UIBarButtonItem, and a UIBarButtonItem *is not a view*. So you can't use auto layout on it. You must set its width manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many way,

Do these Constraints

[image]

[image]

Then create a sub class of UITextField, and do this code

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return CGRectInset(CGRectMake(65, 0, bounds.size.width-65, bounds.size.height) , 0 , 0 )
}

override func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return CGRectInset(CGRectMake(65, 0, bounds.size.width-65, bounds.size.height) , 0 , 0 )
}
}
```

In storyboard/xib, Connect textField to your CustomTextField

[image]

Create outlet for 2 textFields

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField1: CustomTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField2: CustomTextField!
```

in viewDidLoad() method,

```
  var label1 : UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(5, (textField1.frame.height/2)-15, 100, 30))
    label1.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor();
    label1.text = "From:"

    var label2 : UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(5, (textField1.frame.height/2)-15, 100, 30))
    label2.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor();
    label2.text = "To:"

    textField1.addSubview(label1)
    textField2.addSubview(label2)
```

Then you will get output like...

[image]