# How to make UIToolbarItem stretch to full width?

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a view controller with a toolbar. When I add only a `UISlider`:

```
        let slider = UISlider()
        let sliderItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: slider)
        toolbarItems = [sliderItem]
```

it fills the full width of the toolbar.

But if I add a button:

```
        ...
        let buttonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Press", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        toolbarItems = [sliderItem, buttonItem]
```

the slider shrinks to a width of about 1/3 of the screen. Slider and button appear next to each other in the left corner.

I've tried adding a fixed spacer, but that had no effect.

How can I make the slider stretch to fill the remaining width in code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make UIView and contents expand to fill available horizontal space in UIToolbar with Auto Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131432/make-uiview-and-contents-expand-to-fill-available-horizontal-space-in-uitoolbar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **UIStackView** for arranging subviews and UIButton:

[image]

```
    let button = UIButton()
    button.backgroundColor = .blue
    let slider = UISlider()
    let stackView = UIStackView(frame: toolBar.frame)
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    stackView.alignment = .top
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(slider)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
    stackView.spacing = 8.0
    toolBar.items = [UIBarButtonItem(customView: stackView)]
```